# Why is my checkbox not aligning properly ? ThymeLeaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I'm using **ThymeLeaf** for doing this.

I want to align my checkboxes with the 's that got the names of the flavours (sorry, it's in spanish, but the text you see in the picture are ice cream flavours).

[image]

Can you see in the picture that the checkbox appears like if it was hidden ?? I can't even click on them. Why is this happening ?

Can somebody help me and explain me what I'm doing wrong ??

Here's my code:

```css
  h6{
    text-align:center;
}

.tabla{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.tablaInput{
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}

.single-checkbox{
margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="vasoModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Vasito</h4>
        <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
        <form action="" name="vasitoForm">
            <table class="tabla">
                    <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                        <td th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                        <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox"/></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>iv>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the cause, but please be aware that for each `imnput type="checkbox"` with a `th:field` binding, Thymeleaf creates a `input type="hidden"` right after the checkbox.

Comment: Ok .. thanks for that ... It shouldn't be a problem if it's hidden thought !

Comment: I can now see that in the Code Snippet the checkbox appears well and clickable and in my modal it doesn't ... this is even more weird !

Comment: Do you have your site online somewhere? Would be much easier to find the solution...

Comment: No, I only have it locally ... I can upload it to GitHub if wanted but it's built with gradle, Spring and Hibernate and maybe you don't want to take the time to download all the dependencies and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this I've solved the problem adding these lines in the css:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked{
  position: inherit !important;
  left: 50 !important;
  visibility: inherit !important;
}
```

I don't know why, but the checkboxes appear as hidden by default, weird thing !